# How can I refresh datatable when I delete row from datatable with ReactJS without using Redux or Context?

Tags: reactjs, redux, datatable, crud, use-effect

I'm trying to do "CRUD" operations without using "Redux" or anything like that. I am using "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit" for datatable. But after deleting a row in columns I couldn't get the "datatable" to be updated.

**My department page:**

```
import columns from "../../columns/DepartmentColumns";
    const Department = () => {
    
      const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
          getData()
      },[])
      
     
    
      const getData = () => {
        getDepartments().then(x => setDepartments(x.allData))
      }
    }
     <ToolkitProvider
  keyField="id"
  search={true}
  columns={columns}
  data={departments}
  wrapperClasses="table-responsive"
></ToolkitProvider>
   }
```

**My department columns:**

```
import { Button, Col, Row } from "@themesberg/react-bootstrap";
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { deleteDepartment } from "../services/DepartmentService";

 const deleteData = (id) => {
  deleteDepartment(id).then(x => x.statusText)
}

export default [
  {
    dataField: "id",
    text: "ID",
    headerStyle: (column, colIndex) => {
      return { width: "20%" };
    },
  },
  {
    dataField: "name",
    text: "Department Name",
    headerStyle: (column, colIndex) => {
      return { width: "20%" };
    },
  },
  {
    dataField: "action",
    text: "Actions",
    formatter: (cell, row) => {
      const id = row.id
      return (
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} lg={8} sm={12} className="mb-2">
            <Link to={`/department/${id}`}>
              <Button variant="warning" className="w-100">
                Detail
              </Button>
            </Link>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={12} lg={4} sm={12}>
            <Button variant="danger" className="w-100" onClick={() => deleteData(id)}>
              Delete
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      );
    },
    headerStyle: (column, colIndex) => {
      return { width: "20%" };
    },
  },
];
```

**My delete service:**

```
const deleteDepartment = async (id) => {
    const response = await axios.delete(`/Departments/${id}`)
    return{
        statusText: response.statusText
    }
}
```

I can delete the "row" in the "columns" page, but I cannot refresh the data in the "datatable". Because it stays on the "Department.js" page. **What can I do?**

**My datatable:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify your `departments` in your frontend after successfully deleting one in your backend.  Move `deleteData` into your `Department` component and then after you get a successful message that it's been deleted, remove it from your state.

```
const deleteData = (id) => {
  deleteDepartment(id).then((x) => {
    setDepartments(departments.filter(dept => dept.id !== id));
  })
}
```

If it makes sense you can also add a check like `if x.statusText === 'Success'` before you remove the newly deleted department.

Comment: So how do I access the deleteData function in the "Department" component from the "DepartmentColumns" component?

Comment: Remove it from the `DepartmentColumns` component, add it to the `Department` component and pass it to the `DepartmentColumns` component as a prop.

Comment: So how do I pass it as a parameter?
**Datatable**

<ToolkitProvider
      keyField="id"
      search={true}
      columns={columns} // I could not pass it as a parameter in this part.
      data={departments}
      wrapperClasses="table-responsive"
    ></ToolkitProvider>


**columns**
And here is how to capture the parameter.
export default [
  {
    dataField: "id",
    text: "ID",
    headerStyle: (column, colIndex) => {
      return { width: "20%" };
    },
  },